# install sql not work in table Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup

Tags: sql, magento, attributes

My script runs perfect but dont save the new attribute in database.... why? thanks.
`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Itep_Incomm>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Itep_Incomm>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <incomm>
                <class>Itep_Incomm_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>incomm_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </incomm>
        </models>

        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <incomm_virtual translate="label" module="incomm">
                        <label>Incomm Virtual</label>
                        <model>incomm/product_virtual</model>
                        <price_model>incomm/product_price</price_model>
                        <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    </incomm_virtual>
                </type>
            </product>
        </catalog>

        <resources>
            <incomm_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Itep_Incomm</module>
                    <class>Itep_Incomm_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </incomm_setup>
            <incomm_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </incomm_write>
            <incomm_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </incomm_read>
        </resources>

    </global>
</config>
```

Script install in folder `sql/incomm_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

```
    <?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();


    //incomm_request_active_code att order
    $installer->addAttribute('order_item','incomm_request_active_code', 
        array(
            'type' => 'text', 
            'grid' => false 
        )
    );
$installer->endSetup();
```

And the `model/resource/eav/mysql4/setup.php`

```
    <?php
    class Itep_Incomm_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup
    {

}
```

When i run the script, and go to search in database, i cant find the new attribute in table `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup`, but the script shows in `core_resouce`, why my code is not saving? thanks

Comment: The install versions work on Version number.  Perhaps Magento think you've already installed your script?   Maybe  compare your module version definition to what you see in core_resource?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to add an attribute to the sales_flat_order table using a setup resource. You have to alter the table and add the column with some raw sql. I could be wrong.